# Splitting pdf using PyPDF2 is extremely slow and the files are large

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm trying to use PyPDF2 to split a pdf file with several hundred pages into multiple files every 50 pages. The code is as follows:

```py
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger, PdfReader, PdfWriter

def split_pdf(filename, pages_per_file):
    # split pdf file every P pages

    reader = PdfReader(open(filename, "rb"))
    onlyname = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    n = 1
    p0 = 0
    while p0 < (len(reader.pages)):
        writer = PdfWriter()  # writer case
        # writer = PdfMerger()  # merger case

        p1 = min(p0 + pages_per_file, len(reader.pages))

        for page in reader.pages[p0:p1]:
            writer.add_page(page)  # writer case

        # writer.append(reader, pages=(p0, p1))  # merger case

        with open("%s_%d.pdf" % (onlyname, n), "wb") as outfile:
            writer.write(outfile)

        print('write to %s_%d.pdf' % (onlyname, n))
        n += 1
        p0 = p1

split_pdf('path/to/file.pdf', 50)
```

I try `PdfMerger` and `PdfWriter`, and I count the time for each block.

`writer.add_page()` costs ~0.01 seconds which is pretty fast, but `writer.append()` costs ~30 seconds and `writer.write()` costs 20~30 seconds. Why are these two methods so slow?

Another question is the files generated are pretty large, in my case they have almost the same size as the original file. I've checked these files and they have 50 pages indeed.

[image]

Please help me, thank you in advance.

A sample pdf file can be downloaded at [here](https://transfer.sh/fHvESQ/Toole%20-%202017%20-%20Sound%20reproduction%20the%20acoustics%20and%20psychoacoust.pdf), as suggested by K J.

Comment: I read the source code of `pdfbookmarker` which uses `pdfFileMerger`, and is pretty fast. The difference is that `pdfbookmarker` requires pypdf2 in version 1.x and I use 2.11.2.

Comment: For reducing the size of the generated pdfs, have you tried these recommendations from the docs? https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/file-size.html

Comment: @NickODell Yes, I tried `page.compress_content_streams()` but this takes a lot of CPU time but the output size remains the same.

Comment: The time consumption of `writer.write()` seems vary from the input file. I tried with another pdf file and the result shows `writer.add_page()` is still fast and `writer.write()`'s performance varies in a range of 1~30s, although they write the same number of pages.

Comment: @KJ Thank you for replying, I've editted the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @KJ Following up on the fonts angle, the PDF appears to have 341 different fonts, including 242 copies of the Arial font. Output of `pdffonts toole.pdf | wc -l` is 341.

Comment: @NickODell That's terrible. Can I handle it using PyPDF2?

Comment: @DSPnovice No idea - the docs don't mention fonts all much, and it doesn't seem obviously helpful.

Comment: @NickODell I use Microsoft Edge to open the pdf file, Ctrl+P to print and save as pdf, set page range to 1-50, and the resulting file is pretty small.

Comment: @KJ The purpose for splitting is that my printing server consumes a lot of time handling pdf with large amount of pages (it seems not about the file size, just the number of pages, and I don't know why), so I need to split it to several pdfs and print one by one.